# No coverage data after configuring Test Scheme

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, xctest

I enabled code coverage by selecting Test in the scheme and enabled the checkbox labeled Gather Code Coverage.

But for some reason, the coverage tab shows 'No coverage data'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason :
Make sure your target has “Build Active Architecture Only” set to “Yes”. 
If the target is building for more than one architecture no test coverage data will be generated.

[source](http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/121113074922/enabling-code-coverage-in-xcode-7)

Comment: Are you talking about the test target? I'm facing the similar issue where I'm not able to see the coverage data even after enabling it.